# HTML form submit fails to call Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

For the life of me I can't figure this out. I have a simple HTML form that I want to call a Javascript function. Can anyone help me figure out why this isn't working?

Here's a demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/m78z4xty/

Javascript

```
function bbuniformSearch() {
newURL = document.getElementById('qta_field');
this.href='https://www.bestbuyuniforms.com/index.php?fc=module&module=leoproductsearch&controller=productsearch&orderby=position&orderway=desc&cate=&search_query='+newURL;}
```

HTML

```
<form method="POST" name="bbuSearch" onSubmit="bbuniformSearch()">
  <input type="text" id="qta_field" placeholder="Search for items"/>
  <input name="Submit"  type="submit" value="Search Now" onClick="bbuniformSearch()">
  </form>
```

Comment: You're not doing anything to stop the form from being submitted.

Comment: Try using e.preventDefault(); property immediately after the onclick function is being called.

Comment: Why do you need javascript for this in the first place? Just add some hidden inputs and submit to that url using action in form . Also note that `newUrl` is an element...not a value

Comment: How do I do this without using javascript?

Comment: see if [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m78z4xty/9/) works for you.

Comment: @Shivam Perfect, thank you!